# Expected method to read array not found compiling on 10.7

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app I developed on 10.8 and now I am trying to execute the code on 10.7 (as far as I can tell this is an OSX issue). Unfortunately, the following piece of code has stopped working:

```
dataViewController.dataObject = self.pageData[index];
```

It is an object in the dataview controller which is loaded with the current page data. This seems to be part of generated code (if I remember correctly). I am not sure how to get around this issue; how would you tackle this problem on the older versions? Sorry for being a little vague... Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bracket syntax you used is a new compiler feature; it interprets `array[idx]` as the method invocation `'[array  objectAtIndexedSubscript:idx]`.

Unfortunately, the method `- objectAtIndexedSubscript:` itself is only included with newer versions of the SDK, therefore leading to run-time "object does not respond to selector" errors.

To fix, create a category for `NSArray` (and similarly, for `NSDictionary` and others), and add the method

```
- (id)objectAtIndexedSubscript:(NSUInteger)idx {
  return [self objectAtIndex:idx];
}
```